# Hide Selected Columns using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have this data
[image]

I want to make a button for Hide and a button for Unhide.

Suppose each column is labeled with Date from January 2010 to January 2016.
I want to unhide all columns with Date March and automatically hide all non March columns.

It turns out if cell.entirecolumn.Hidden = cell.value = Range("I1") is True then column with cell value in a range will hide.

Suppose I have a column with headers A to Z how to make this in a sense that if range ("A1") contains A then all columns with A will unhide and all columns that do not will hide.

```
Sub Hide_Columns()
    Dim cell As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each cell In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A1:F1"))
        cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = cell.Value = Range("I1") And Not IsEmpty(cell)
    Next cell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub Show_All_Columns()
    Columns.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Comment: The easiest way (without VBA) would be grouping all march columns and then using the [1] and [2] buttons of the [grouping feature](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-08CE98C4-0063-4D42-8AC7-8278C49E9AFF) to toggle visability.

Comment: Should this button toggle only March visibility? Have you written any code yet?

Comment: Not Yet, because im just a beginner in VBA programing.. i think toggle grouping feature works only for rows??? i didn't try yet... =)..

Comment: sorry what i mean for the button is a command click in VBA excel.. if  i input March in Input box then clicked unhide.. all date march 2010, 2011,2012... will unhide else all non March column will hide.. Hope this will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use Google before ask here.
I think that you could start with this:

```
Sub HideCols()
    Columns("A:BZ").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True ''Hide
End Sub

Sub ShowCols()
    Columns("A:BZ").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False ''Unhide
End Sub
```

and then parametrize the `Columns("A:BZ").Select` with some if statements. Finally add a button that call the two Subs.

Comment: Or both procedures as single line:  `Columns("A:BZ").EntireColumn.Hidden = Not Columns("A:BZ").EntireColumn.Hidden`

Comment: Thank you for sharing.. I need a little help for my codes. this turns ou that if cell.entirecolumn.Hidden = cell.value = Range("I1")  is True then column with cell value In a range will hide.. Supposed that i have column  with headers A to Z how to make this in a sense that if range ("A1") contains A then All columns with A will unhide and all columns that is not will hide... here is my code

Comment: Sub Hide_Columns()
    Dim cell As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each cell In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A1:F1"))
        cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = cell.Value = Range("I1") And Not IsEmpty(cell)
    Next cell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub Show_All_Columns()
    Columns.Hidden = False
End Sub